# consecutive numbers into array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the best way to check for consecutive numbers.
Right now i have made an array with the numbers i wanna check for, but instead off writing them manually, I will like to instead make an algorithm that calculate the numbers for me, and only stop after a number i desire.

```
var findAllClass = $('.someClass').length;
var changeClassArr = [0, 7, 10, 17, 20, 27, 30];// change this from manually to automatic calculated 
$(function(){
  for (i = 0; i < findAllClass; i++){
    $('.someClass').each(function(i,n){
      if (i == changeClassArr) {
        $(n).addClass('giveNewClass');
      };
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Is this always those 6 numbers? Or you need to generate them more using some pattern?

Comment: Comparing a number to an array will never match  `if (i == changeClassArr)`, did you mean `indexOf()>-1`?

Comment: so far I have actually only used If ( i == 0 | i == 7 etc... ) and I made only the array, as I was trying to make the question easier to show, but as @baao mentioned that won't work without using indexOf()....

Comment: `var n, step = 3; for (n = 0; n <= 30; step = step < 7 ? 7 : 3, n += step) {...}`

Comment: @Teemu thankyou,  work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the array like so:

```
var list = [];
var stopAt = 30;
var incrementor = 0;    

while (incrementor <= stopAt) {
  if (incrementor % 10 === 0 || (incrementor - 7) % 10 === 0) {
    list.push(incrementor);
  }
  incrementor++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using ES6, you can use following generator:

```js
function *numbers() {
  var x;
  yield x = 0;
  
  while(true) {
    yield x += 7;
    yield x += 3;
  }
}

for (x of numbers()) {
  if (x > 30) {
    break;
  }

  console.log(x);
}
```